# Using MAX in SQL statements

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to learn how to use SQL to pull certain information. I am using PHPMyAdmin for SQL. Here is the structure:

> author (ID, FirstName, LastName, YearOfBirth, Gender, LivingCityID)
>
> book (ID, Name, Type, YearPublished, PublisherID, SoldBookCount)
>
> writes (BookID, AuthorID)
>
> city (ID, CityName, Country)
>
> publisher (ID, PublisherName, PublisherCityID)

Here are some attempts to get different info. Is this how I would do it?

This to get the the author who have sold the most books, showing the author
ID and sold book count.

```
SELECT w.AuthorID, MAX(b.SoldBookCount)
FROM book as b, writes as w, author as a
WHERE b.ID = w.BookID AND a.ID = w.AuthorID
```

This to find the author and book type pair, whose total sold book count
is the biggest, showing author ID, book Type, and sold book count.

```
SELECT w.AuthorID, b.Type, MAX(b.SoldBookCount)
FROM book as b, writes as w, author as a
WHERE b.ID = w.BookID AND a.ID = w.AuthorID
```

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax

Comment: Check out `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get you the sold book counts for each author/book pair, using explicit `JOIN` clauses. I like to put the join condition into the `ON` rather than `WHERE`.

```
SELECT a.ID, b.ID, b.SoldBookCount
FROM author as a
    JOIN writes AS w ON w.AuthorID = a.ID
    JOIN book AS b ON w.BookID = b.ID
```

You can get the total number of books sold for each other by using `GROUP BY` and `SUM`:

```
SELECT a.ID, SUM(b.SoldBookCount)
FROM author as a
    JOIN writes AS w ON w.AuthorID = a.ID
    JOIN book AS b ON w.BookID = b.ID
GROUP BY a.ID
```

Finally, you can get the author with the most sold books with an additional query with `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`

```
SELECT authorID, totalSoldCount
FROM (
    SELECT a.ID as authorID, SUM(b.SoldBookCount) as totalSoldCount
    FROM author as a
        JOIN writes AS w ON w.AuthorID = a.ID
        JOIN book AS b ON w.BookID = b.ID
    GROUP BY a.ID
) as t
ORDER BY totalSoldCount DESC
LIMIT 1
```

There are a lot of variations available here. For example, everywhere I've put `SELECT a.ID` you could have `SELECT w.authorID` and it would be the same result.

Actually, I think you can do the last query as a single query:

```
SELECT a.ID as authorID, SUM(b.SoldBookCount) as totalSoldCount
FROM author as a
    JOIN writes AS w ON w.AuthorID = a.ID
    JOIN book AS b ON w.BookID = b.ID
GROUP BY a.ID
ORDER BY SUM(b.SoldBookCount) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

---

Since you asked specifically, `MAX` will select the maximum value in that column, but it doesn't select the *row* that has that value. So you can get the maximum number of books sold with this:

```
SELECT MAX(SoldBookCount)
FROM book
```

But in order to get the id of the boox with the most sales, you have to do this (like above)

```
SELECT ID, SoldBookCount
FROM book
ORDER BY SoldBookCount DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Another option would be to compute the max value and then select the book(s) that have that number of books sold

```
SELECT ID, SoldBookCount
FROM book
WHERE SoldBookCount=MAX(SoldBookCount)
```

This may be slower, but has the advantage of selecting several books if there is a tie for first. You could use the same idea for the author(s) with the most books sold.